# Cannot run Python from Cron

Tags: python, cron, subprocess, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that will read the temperature of from a probe on the GPIO pins of a Raspberry-Pi, and will append that temperature to a log file. Running the script form terminal with sudo permissions works fine:

```
sudo python /home/pi/temp.py
```

I've attempted to run the script every 15 minutes from sudo's crontab file with the line:

```
*/15 * * * * python /home/pi/temp.py
```

This fails, with the output being

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['modprobe', 'w1-gpio'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I know the issue is with the modprobe subprocess call, but I can't identify what exactly. In my script, I have the following code related to the issue:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['modprobe', 'w1-gpio'])
subprocess.call(['modprobe', 'w1-therm'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `cron` has its own `PATH` variable and doesn't use the same path that you do.
For that reason, it would be advisable to call any programs that you use (especially through python's `subprocess`) with an absolute path to the executable

You could do `which modprobe` on the commandline to find where `modprobe` lives (probably in `/bin/`), and then change your call in `subprocess.py` to `subprocess.call(['/bin/modprobe', 'w1-gpio'])`

Comment: This was it. My modprobe lived in `/sbin/`, but adding this to the subprocess.call in my `temp.py` script solved my issue. Many thanks!